# Unlogged user cannot see store and must go to login and successfully logged in users must be redirected to store

Tags: wordpress, redirect, hook-woocommerce

I am working on a Wordpress site with Woocommerce. **I am using this function inside functions.php** to redirect everyone who visits my store to login since it is a private area. Once the person logs in, they should be redirected to the store again. I have the following code implemented, which works for me to get all those trying to navigate my store to log in, **I need to modify this code so that once logged in, it redirects me to the store page in woocommerce**, in my case the page of the store is called "tienda".

**To clarify:** **Users who are not registered or logged in, should not be able to see the store or cart or anything from woocommerce**, *I already implemented this with a wp-members plugin*, if they try to navigate these woocommerce urls, they must go to login. **When you have already logged in, you should go to the store, in my case you should not redirect to the previous link, but must inevitably go to the page called "tienda"**.

On the other hand, I would like to know if my function is missing something or is well built. Thank you!

```
function loggedoutuser_redirect() {
    if (
        ! is_user_logged_in()
        && (is_woocommerce() || is_cart() || is_checkout())
    ) {
        header('Location: ' . wp_login_url());
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'loggedoutuser_redirect');
```

Comment: Could you please confirm did the solution resolved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
function woocommerce_login_redirect_custom( $redirect, $user ) {
    $redirect = wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' );
    return $redirect;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'woocommerce_login_redirect_custom', 10, 2 );
```

Paste this above snippet at the end of your active child theme `functions.php` file or else if you are good in plugin development then create a custom plugin.

**Snippet Explanation:**

1. Create a custom function to redirect after logged in
2. Fetch the shop URL using WooCommerce helper function `wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' )` and assign it to the variable `$redirect`
3. Then return the URL
4. Hook the custom function to the filter hook `woocommerce_login_redirect`

> Note: You can check the user role inside our custom function then based on the role you can redirect it to the dashboard if he is administrator else to the shop page.